# Django authentication urls.py with namespace

Tags: django, django-registration

I wanted to manage a separate urls.py with a namespace.

```
conf/
    urls.py (1)
common/
    urls.py (2)
```

(1) is system-wide urls.py which is installed by Django, and I made (2) which has index page and "accounts" authentication pages.

(1) urls.py includes common.url with namespace "common"

```
url(r'^', include('common.urls', namespace='common')),
```

(2) urls.py declares as follows:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='register'),
url(r'^accounts/register/done/$', UserCreateDoneTemplateView.as_view(), name='register_done'),
```

The following urls are correctly reversed by Django.

```
{% url 'common:login' %}
{% url 'common:logout' %}
{% url 'common:password_change' %}
{% url 'common:register' %}
```

However, "common:password_change_done" is not reversed, and I encountered "NoReverseMatch" error.

Of course, url declarations are placed in system-wide urls.py (1). I'm just wondering if it's possible to split it into a separate app (2).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the full error and traceback?

Comment: The Django auth urls are already in the namespace `auth`. Try `{% url 'auth:login' %}` or `{% url 'common:auth:login' %}`

Comment: @Alasdair I'm sorry for the very late feedback.

I didn't include auth.urls, but I knew that the following views need to set "success_url" with correct namespace.

    PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('common:password_change_done')),     

    PasswordResetView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('common:password_reset_done')),

    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('common:password_reset_complete')),

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you have solved your problem, you can add it as an answer. If you are still stuck, then please edit your original question.

Comment: @Alasdair, I'm sorry for my poor English, and I hope my post below to help you understand. Thank you.

Comment: No need to apologize. Glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think my question and answer were vague and very confusing because of my poor English.

Firstly, I wanted to make my urls with "/account" prefix like this:

```
/accounts/register
/accounts/login
/accounts/logout
```

I wanted to reuse 'django.contrib.auth.urls' with the namespace like 'common' or 'account to manage urls separately'

However, the success urls of following views are hard-coded. It means that we have to follow the their rules naming convention.

```
PasswordChangeView
PasswordResetView
PasswordResetConfirmView
```

For example, in case of "PasswordChangeView" are implemented as follows:

```
class PasswordChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_change_done')
    template_name = 'registration/password_change_form.html'
    title = _('Password change')
    ... omitted ...
```

Thus, I decided not to include 'django.contrib.auth.urls', and I declared url patterns by myself.

I thought defining inherited class of "PasswordChangeView", but I knew that Django supports pass member field of view class.

```
url(
    r'^password_change/$',
    PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')),
    name='password_change'
),
```

Now, I don't see reverse error.

I hope my question/answer could be helpful for someone else. Thank you.